# preconditioners for matrices arising out of PDEs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-differential-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

Suppose I have the heat the following one dimensional PDE for the heat equation:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t } = \alpha \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2 }
$$
which I discretized in the spatial domain to give me a Linear Time invariant system of the form (based on some given boundary conditions):
$$
\dot{u}(t) = Au(t) + b(t)
$$
Note that $A$ is independent of time. My question is: are there any special preconditioners for $A$ obtained as above which make use of the fact that $A$ is obtained from a PDE? In Chapter 5 of [1], the authors say that "*Good preconditioning strategies have derived for specific type of matrices, in particular, those arising from discretization of PDEs*". But nothing is concrete is mentioned and no reference is given.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[1] Jorge Nocedal, S. Wright. Numerical Optimization. Springer-Verlag New York, 2006. ISBN: 978-0-387-30303-1. 2nd edition.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but Feynman-Kac?